# Change if/else on switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, switch-statement

Good Day! Want to change my if\else statement on switch.

I have this working code.

```
$tbody.append([
'<td class="view">' + (row.age === '1' ? '18' : row.age === '2'  ? '18-24' : row.age === '3' ? '25-35' : row.age === '4' ? '35+' : 'any' ) + '</td>',
]);
```

I've tried to replace it with this construction:

```
        var text= 0;

        switch (row.age) {
          case 0:
            text= "any";
            break;
          case 1:
            text = "18";
            break;
          case 2:
            text = "18-24";
            break;
          case 3:
            text = "25-34";
            break;
          case 3:
            text = "35+";
            break;
        }

$tbody.append([
                '<td class="view">' + text + '</td>',
]);
```

But it doesn't work. It always gives 0 as a result. Any thoughts?

Comment: what do you mean "it doesnt work"? please elaborate. it doesn't do anything? it appends the wrong thing?

Comment: @Jesse updated my question

Comment: `row.age` seems to be a string, compare to strings in `case`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `row.age` is a string, then you need to put `case` value as `string` OR `integer` if row.age is integer.

```
switch (row.age) {
          case '0':
            text= "any";
            break;
          case '1':
            text = "18";
            break;
          case '2':
            text = "18-24";
            break;
          case '3':
            text = "25-34";
            break;
          case '3':
            text = "35+";
            break;
        }
```

From your question, the `if-else` says `row.age` is string, so in `switch-case` block you must compare that as integer. Because, switch match like
`===` strict matching.

Answer (score 0):

`row.age === '1'` and `case 1` are different. The first one is a string and the second one is an int

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `[` , `]` at `.append()` , which returns error

`NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element is null.`

```js
var row = {};
row.age = 1;
var text = "";

switch (row.age) {
  case 0:
    text = "any";
    break;
  case 1:
    text = "18";
    break;
  case 2:
    text = "18-24";
    break;
  case 3:
    text = "25-34";
    break;
  case 3:
    text = "35+";
    break;
}


$("body").append("<span>" + text + "</span>")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```